# why not recommended to use Jquery DataTable?

Tags: jquery, datatable, pageload

I am working on improve performance for a page that shows students information list ( around 10000 students).
the page using datatable to show the list, but its very slow. 
My team leader suggested to replace the datatable with another thing to show the list because datatable is very slow, but I read an article says:

"if you are working with seriously large databases, you might want to consider using the server-side options that DataTables provides".

what is the correct way to show list of huge data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do server paging, it means that on each page call will call the server and get current page data.

When using server-side paging the client and server will server a small amount of date (current page data only).

Also, Its Lazy Loading.

> Lazy mode is handy to deal with large datasets, instead of loading the
>   entire data, small chunks of data is loaded by invoking onLazyLoad
>   callback everytime paging, sorting and filtering happens.

Answer (score 1):

This is only an optional way to use of it, you not force to use.
When you use of none server option, DataTable work for the page that already show in browser, but when use of server options, it may help you to have more functionality.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery data tables are one of the fastest ways of displaying data. It provides a feature where you can navigate to other data pages. Just don't load all the data rows or large amounts of data. Even phpMyAdmin becomes slow if you display all the data rows per page.